# How to bind Spring Boot LiveReload server to localhost only?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, livereload

I've installed the Spring Boot Developer tools. After running the application, I've noticed that the [LiveReload server](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-livereload) open by default the TCP port 35729 on all network interfaces (eth0, lo, ...).

I've seen that I can disable this server with :

```
spring.devtools.livereload.enabled=false
```

but I would like to keep the LiveReload server running only on localhost.

How to do it?

Comment: By default the web server listens on all interfaces (I think). You can control that with `server.address` in your properies/yml file. You might see if that also manages the interfaces for livereload?

Comment: I've already set `server.address=127.0.0.1` but it doesn't act on the LiveReload server.

Comment: Okay, that's the extent of my knowledge on the subject. :) Sorry.

Comment: When you say 'all interfaces', do you mean on all 'environments'? Meaning, local, test, production? something like that?

Comment: I mean `all interfaces` in the sense of a network interface such as eth0, lo,..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming in dev you use localhost and in prod not using localhost

Write in **application-dev.properties** not in **application-prod.properties**
That way you can use only in localhost